# Need to translate code using "exp/utf8string" into later standard library code

Tags: utf-8, go

I am trying to ran an example from [**The Go Programming Language Phrasebook**](http://books.google.com/books/about/The_Go_Programming_Language_Phrasebook.html?id=scyH562VXZUC) - the book was written in 2012, based on Go 1.0 . The example uses the `exp/utf8string` package, which has now become `unicode/utf8`. I am currently using Go 1.2.1 and code listed below will not compile as is, since the `exp/utf8string` package is now defunct:

```
package main
import "strings"
import "unicode"
import "exp/utf8string"
import "fmt"

func main()
{
    str := "\tthe important rôles of utf8 text\n"
    str = strings.TrimFunc(str, unicode.IsSpace)

    // The wrong way
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", str[0:len(str)/2])
    // The right way
    u8 := utf8string.NewString(str)
    FirstHalf := u8.Slice(0, u8.RuneCount()/2)
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", FirstHalf)

}
```

I am a still a GoLang newbie, so I'm not sure how the older experimental packages were integrated into the standard library. I did a bit of research and found that `utf8string.NewString(str)` is now`expvar.NewString(str)`, so I changed my imports to

```
expvar
unicode
```

and modified the code appropriately to call `expvar.NewString(str)`,but I'm still getting two errors:

```
u8.Slice undefined (type *expvar.String has no field or method Slice)
u8.RuneCount undefined (type *expvar.String has no field or method RuneCount)
```

I've tried a few different ways but can't seem to get it to work.

How should this example code be written for GoLang 1.2.1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install package `utf8string`:

```
$ go get -v code.google.com/p/go.exp/utf8string
code.google.com/p/go.exp (download)
code.google.com/p/go.exp/utf8string
$
```

Fix the program:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
    "unicode"

    "code.google.com/p/go.exp/utf8string"
)

func main() {
    str := "\tthe important rôles of utf8 text\n"
    str = strings.TrimFunc(str, unicode.IsSpace)

    // The wrong way
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", str[0:len(str)/2])
    // The right way
    u8 := utf8string.NewString(str)
    FirstHalf := u8.Slice(0, u8.RuneCount()/2)
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", FirstHalf)
}
```

Output:

```
the important r
the important rô
```

Revising the program to only use Go 1.2.1 standard packages:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    str := "\tthe important rôles of utf8 text\n"
    str = strings.TrimSpace(str)

    // The wrong way
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", str[0:len(str)/2])
    // The right way
    r := []rune(str)
    FirstHalf := string(r[:len(r)/2])
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", FirstHalf)
}
```

Output:

```
the important r
the important rô
```

Comment: So what you mean is that I could still install the deprecated package `exp/utf8string` and compile that example code as is, even though it's no longer necessary with the revision using 1.2.1 standard packages. I have no need to do it the old way, and using the 1.2.1 in the way you did works fine. The lesson is the same regardless: Count runes, not bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the UTF8 package  (http://golang.org/pkg/unicode/utf8/)

- utf8.RuneCountInString - http://golang.org/pkg/unicode/utf8/#RuneCountInString

The example is extremely odd because there's no need to call "NewString" to create a UTF8 string—all strings in Go are UTF8 by default.

I'd suggest finding another resource since that Phrasebook seems so out of date as to be misleading.

Try "Go By Example" and "Way To Go".

Comment: The book itself I've found to be quite good - deep and concise, and this is the first time I've had a problem with an example and I'm nearly halfway through. (I have "Way to Go" - excellent, but it's a fat book.) I believe the author explains in another place that it's  good practice to make a copy of a string for manipulation (did not quite understand why...) which I believe is the reason for the call to `NewString()`. At any rate, I had already tried `utf8.RuneCountInString()` but I still get `Slice undefined`

Comment: Check the package docs: there is no Slice function. Look in the `strings` package for Split. Also note that u8.Split won't work: Split isn't a method (read the official docs on method receivers). All strings are copied by default.

Comment: `Slice()` did sound odd to me. Maybe it's something from the old experiment packages. And I don't think `Split()` is what's needed. I get the point of the example: count by runes, not by bytes - don't really need to compile it. But I like to build an example and then tinker with it - maybe I'll just skip it this time.